# how to check if an issue has been exalated in Jira Scriptrunner, [Static type checking] - The variable [eventTypeManager] is undeclared

Tags: jira, scriptrunner-for-jira

I would like to write some code to check if an event has been exalated in scriptrunner, I am using the following code but it seems that I have a compilation error: I am getting the error stating that [Static type checking] - The variable [eventTypeManager] is undeclared. I am importing the appropriate packages though, how can I fix this problem

```
  import com.atlassian.jira.event.issue.AbstractIssueEventListener
import com.atlassian.jira.event.issue.IssueEvent
import com.atlassian.jira.event.type.EventType
import com.atlassian.jira.event.type.EventTypeManager
import com.atlassian.jira.*
import com.atlassian.jira.component.pico.ComponentManager
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.CustomFieldManager
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.fields.CustomField
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.MutableIssue
import com.atlassian.jira.bc.issue.IssueService
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.Issue
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.IssueManager
import org.slf4j.Logger
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
 
class DefaultAccountListener extends AbstractIssueEventListener {
 
    private final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DefaultAccountListener)
 
    private static final String EXALATED_EVENT_TYPE = "com.exalate.api.domain.trigger.EXALATED"
    private static final String EXALATE_UPDATED_EVENT_TYPE = "com.exalate.api.domain.trigger.UPDATED"
 
    @Override
    void customEvent(IssueEvent event) {
        Issue issue = event.issue
        EventType eventType = eventTypeManager.getEventType(event.getEventTypeId())
        LOG.debug("Custom event caught for issue ${issue.key}: type [${eventType.type}], name [${eventType.name}], nameKey [${eventType.nameKey}]")
 
        if (eventType.name.equalsIgnoreCase(EXALATED_EVENT_TYPE)) {
            LOG.debug("EXALATED event caught for issue ${issue.key}")
        }
    }
}
```